# Why does this list return an Int rather than an object?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
  Tcard.attack(self.players[self.opponent])
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'attack'
```

This is the error I get from calling `attack()`.

```
Tcard = self.players[self.turn].returnCard()
Tcard.attack(self.players[self.opponent])
```

For some odd reason when Tcard.attack() calls with the parameters self.players[self.opponent], the list returns an int ranther than a Player object. Can someone please explain why it is returning an int rather than an object?

Here is the code for the whole file:

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []
        self.turn = 0
        self.opponent = 1

    def prepare_game(self):
        AI_1 = AI("AI_1", 1000)
        AI_1.generate_inventory()
        AI_2 = AI("AI_2", 1000)
        AI_2.generate_inventory()
        self.players.append(AI_1)
        self.players.append(AI_2)


    def start(self):
        p1 = self.players[self.turn]
        p2 = self.players[self.opponent]

        Tcard = self.players[self.turn].returnCard()
        print "Battle time"

        print "%s attacked %s" % (p1.Name, p2.Name)
        Tcard.attack(self.players[self.opponent])
        #switch
        if self.turn == 0:
            self.turn = 1
            self.opponent = 0
            self.start()
        else:
            self.turn = 0
            self.opponent = 1
            self.start()
```

Here is where the function returnCard is at:

```
class AI():
    def __init__(self, Name, Health):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Health = Health
        self.inventory = []

    def generate_inventory(self):
        #Generate 6 Cards and 3 Power-ups
        #rand_powerups = random.randint(min(len(powerup)), max(len(powerup)))
        rand_cards = random.randint(0, 4)
        #self.inventory.append(rand_powerups)
        while len(self.inventory) != 4:
            self.inventory.append(rand_cards)
            if len(self.inventory) == 4:
                break



    def returnCard(self):
        return self.inventory[random.randrange(0, 4)]
```

Comment: without seeing the code it is literally impossible to say

Comment: Second that, we need to see the code for the Tcard class in particular

Comment: `Tcard.attack()` isn't being called at all, because `Tcard` is an `int` and therefore has no `attack()` method. As to why that's happening, you'd have to show us more code.

Comment: where is `returnCard()`? surely it returns an int? So Tcard is therefore an int

Comment: self.inventory contains ints from `self.inventory.append(rand_cards)` so you are setting Tcard equal to an int. if you want to call instance methods you should be creating an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def returnCard(self):
   return self.inventory[random.randrange(0, 4)]
```

`returnCard` returns a random item of `self.inventory`.

And `self.inventory` is filled by `generate_inventory` which does this:

```
# generate a random *INT*
rand_cards = random.randint(0, 4)
while len(self.inventory) != 4:
    # append that *INT*
    self.inventory.append(rand_cards)
    # (note that this keeps adding the same number over and over)
```

So, of course, `returnCard` will return an int here:

```
Tcard = self.players[self.turn].returnCard()
```

So when you try to call `attack` you try to call it on an int:

```
Tcard.attack(self.players[self.opponent])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   self.inventory = [] # a list


   rand_cards = random.randint(0, 4)

   self.inventory.append(rand_cards) # you add ints to the list

    # you return an int
   return self.inventory[random.randrange(0, 4)]

 # you set Tcard equal to an int  returned from ^^
 Tcard = self.players[self.turn].returnCard()
```

On another note you should use range to add the random ints and keep calling randint or you will just get the same number added to your list:

```
def generate_inventory(self):
    for _ in range(4):
        self.inventory.append(random.randint(0, 4))
```

If you want to use the methods in your class, create an instance. I could give you an example but I have no idea where attack comes from.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Tcard` becomes a variable due to this line:

```
Tcard = self.players[self.turn].returnCard()
```

By assigning `Tcard` the result of `.returnCard()` which will always be an integer since you made `returnCard()` to return an integer with:

```
return self.inventory[random.randrange(0, 4)]
```

So since an integer can't have any attributes, that will be an error. Thus the raised error saying that an `int` has no attribute.

Second, `Tcard` is not even a function. Only functions can have attributes thus adding more to the error. You need to create a function for `Tcard` to be able to work. Add something like:

```
class Tcard:
    def attack():
        #Do something
```

Comment: I think instances can have attributes

Comment: Your terminology is quite off. *Objects* can have attributes, and in Python, everything is an object. Integer objects do have a `real` attribute for example. And creating a class is not making `Tcard` a function.